# What is the Limit of the Broadcom Architecture?

Tags: pi-3

When I read the spec sheet for the Raspberry Pi 3, I was both excited and slightly disappointed. Excited because the Raspberry Pi Foundation continues to release Raspberry Pis with ever increasing CPU performance, so it is actually usable as a computer now. Also they have continued to add features, for example the on board Bluetooth and Wi-Fi. But disappointed because there is still no USB 3.0.

And this leads me onto my point.

There is a limit to how much further they can go with the current architecture of the Broadcom chip they use on the Pi. So surely this means there will be a point were to add more features (USB 3.0), they will have to use a newer architecture? And if this point is reached, would projects made on older generation Raspberry Pis be supported?

Comment: This question invites *a lot* of speculation, and I'm not sure it's possible to give a really good answer without comment from the Pi Foundation. That said, the Pi Foundation appears to be extremely conscious of backwards-compatibility issues, and have committed to continuing to sell older board models as long as people continue to buy them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking around you can find different comments from interviews and articles which indicate both new features and new products as well as stability in established products.

From an [article in makezine](http://makezine.com/2016/02/28/eben-upton-talks-about-the-new-raspberry-pi-3/%20%22makezine.com) we get specific mentions of USB3.0:

> **The future of Raspbian**
>
> I think a lot of people forget the Foundation’s educational mission, and the importance it places on backwards compatibility with the 8 million Raspberry Pi’s already out there. When you’re dealing with computers in a classroom, not making all your teaching materials out of date overnight is vital.

and

> **The future holds new boards**
>
> “*I’d like to see USB 3.0 added, as it really is the universal solution for adding peripherals — especially higher bandwidth ones like disk drives, network interfaces — and removes the requirements for things like SATA*”
>   — James Adams, Director of Hardware Engineering, Raspberry Pi
>
> But while I think any hypothetical Raspberry Pi 4 may well have USB 3.0 at this point, I also think the new Raspberry Pi 3 will almost certainly have a longer life than the Raspberry Pi 2. Perhaps two, or maybe even three, years rather than the one that the Raspberry Pi 2 survived. So don’t hold your breath waiting.

As for the frequency of major hardware updates we can look at [TechRepublic](http://makezine.com/2016/02/28/eben-upton-talks-about-the-new-raspberry-pi-3/):

> **Can we expect a new Raspberry Pi each year from now on?**
>
> Upton is adamant that the foundation is not about to start bringing out new Raspberry Pi boards each year. The rapid release Pi 3 is something of a one-off, he said, made possible by a combination of technical and cost factors. The earlier work the foundation completed on designing the Pi 2 paved the way to begin using the more powerful chipset found in the Pi 3. This technical readiness coincided with a reduction in the cost of producing the board, which allowed wi-fi and Bluetooth support to be added without increasing the price.
>
> "*We're kind of at the end of that particular roadmap. I would expect a longer pause, a couple of years at least, before any kind of major bump to the platform*," he said.